# pydrake - How to get cartesian pose of end effector for connections: plant.get_body_poses_output_port()?

Tags: python, drake

Ubuntu 20.04 | Python 3.7 | drake 0.38.0 | PyCharm | Scripting in pydrake:

I need to generate a connection between the current pose in Cartesian space of a robotic end-effector and a controller's input port.

get_body_poses_output_port() seems the obvious solution, with some manipulation to:

(1) obtain only the RigidTranform for the last body (the end-effector)
(2) convert this RigidTransform into it's rotational and translational components
(3) stack those together for input to a homebrew controller that expects that input.

I am trying to do (1) with:
(where the demultiplexer should take in n_dof+1 bodies that each have 9 components and split them up into n_dof+1 outputs)
demux = builder.AddSystem(Demultiplexer(np.full(n_dof+1,9)))
builder.Connect(plant.get_body_poses_output_port(), demux.get_input_port())

but I get the following error:
RuntimeError: DiagramBuilder::Connect: Cannot mix vector-valued and abstract-valued ports while connecting output port body_poses of System plant to input port u0 of System drake/systems/Demultiplexer@00000000040505c0

When I look at the data_type of the get_body_poses_output_port() it's a combination of vector-valued and abstract_valued ports.

Is there another way to retrieve the port I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the Demultiplexer doesn't support abstract types (and that the body poses output port is abstract-typed). You can write a tiny leaf system to extract the single body pose that you want.  I have one example [here](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/e847a6eba01aa276d69e3af29446a0c4d1de11c8/manipulation/scenarios.py#L305-L322).